# I am converting a HTML, CSS, JS template to Angular but for some reason the JS wont run

Tags: angular

I have tried everything, the js file works, if I put a pop up in the js files it runs, but my custom js for scrollreveal and the changing of active links in the nav dont work.

I have attached my git repo https://github.com/driggy769/my-portfolio/ because maybe someone can point me where I am going wrong.

I am new to Angular so maybe its something silly that can be easily resolved

Tried putting the js in the JSON, in the index and inline, but the main.js just doesnt work

This is my index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>MyPortfolio</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <link href='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/boxicons@2.0.5/css/boxicons.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/scrollreveal"></script>
  <script src="src/assets/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my main.js File

```
const showMenu = (toggleId, navId) =>{
    const toggle = document.getElementById(toggleId),
    nav = document.getElementById(navId)

    if(toggle && nav){
        toggle.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
            nav.classList.toggle('show')
        })
    }
}

showMenu('nav-toggle','nav-menu')

/*===== REMOVE MENU MOBILE =====*/
const navLink = document.querySelectorAll('.nav__link')

function linkAction(){
    const navMenu = document.getElementById('nav-menu')
    navMenu.classList.remove('show')
}
navLink.forEach(n => n.addEventListener('click', linkAction))

/*===== SCROLL SECTIONS ACTIVE LINK =====*/
const sections = document.querySelectorAll('section[id]')

window.addEventListener('scroll', scrollActive)

function scrollActive(){
    const scrollY = window.pageYOffset

    sections.forEach(current =>{
        const sectionHeight = current.offsetHeight
        const sectionTop = current.offsetTop - 50;
        sectionId = current.getAttribute('id')

        if(scrollY > sectionTop && scrollY <= sectionTop + sectionHeight){
            document.querySelector('.nav__menu a[href*=' + sectionId + ']').classList.add('active')
        }else{
            document.querySelector('.nav__menu a[href*=' + sectionId + ']').classList.remove('active')
        }
    })
}

/*===== SCROLL REVEAL ANIMATION =====*/
const sr = ScrollReveal({
    origin: 'top',
    distance: '80px',
    duration: 2000,
    reset: true
})

/*SCROLL HOME*/
sr.reveal('.home__title', {})
sr.reveal('.home__scroll', {delay: 200})
sr.reveal('.home__img', {origin:'right', delay: 400})

/*SCROLL ABOUT*/
sr.reveal('.about__img', {delay: 500})
sr.reveal('.about__subtitle', {delay: 300})
sr.reveal('.about__profession', {delay: 400})
sr.reveal('.about__text', {delay: 500})
sr.reveal('.about__social-icon', {delay: 600, interval: 200})

/*SCROLL SKILLS*/
sr.reveal('.skills__subtitle', {})
sr.reveal('.skills__name', {distance: '20px', delay: 50, interval: 100})
sr.reveal('.skills__img', {delay: 400})

/*SCROLL PORTFOLIO*/
sr.reveal('.portfolio__img', {interval: 200})

/*SCROLL CONTACT*/
sr.reveal('.contact__subtitle', {})
sr.reveal('.contact__text', {interval: 200})
sr.reveal('.contact__input', {delay: 400})
sr.reveal('.contact__button', {delay: 600})
```

Comment: Please share your code directly in snippets on your question. Saying "doesn't work" isn't very clear either. Please do your best to describe the desired behaviour, the current non-working behaviour and what you've tried in order to fix it.

Comment: Im unsure what code to share, the main.js file?

Comment: It looks like you’re simply trying to copy paste a JS app into an Angular app. I’d suggest you do things the Angular way, because that’s the only way you’ll get it working.